# If conditions performances in Blade templates in Laravel

Tags: php, performance, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I've just a simple questions about performances using **blade** templating inside **Laravel** framework. Let's talk about big size projects.

I'm interested to know if it's more performant-wise to implement the if conditions like this:

```
@if(isset($training))
  <a class="btn" href="{{MYLIB\URL::training_url($sector, $category, $training)}}">Nu inschrijven<span class="icon-right"></span></a>
@endif
```

or like this?

```
<?php if (isset($page)){ ?>
  <h2>{{{ $page->title }}}</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blade syntax compiles to raw PHP. That means this:

```
@if(isset($page))
    <h2>{{{ $page->title }}}</h2>
@endif
```

Becomes this:

```
<?php if(isset($page)): ?>
    <h2><?php echo e($page->title); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This compiled template is then stored in `storage/framework/views` (`app/storage/views` in Laravel 4)

#### Conclusion

The only performance hit you get is the compiling. This ideally will only happen when the view file changes or is accessed the first time. If you ask me you surely have other performance bottlenecks to worry about first. (Especially things like database queries or just bad architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel simply converts the blade syntax to a normal php syntax inside temporary view files on the first pass, which are stored in `/app/storage`.

So there is basically no performance difference between `blade` and regular `php` commands

Answer (score 0):

As laravel compiles and caches templates anyway, the only slight overhead is on the very first access to the blade template, and after that there would be no difference in performance at all